# How do i confirm that my http-server was closed properly?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I am creating an expressjs app and for the sake of testing i "promisified" my server start:

```
startHttpServer(): Promise<any> {
    let self = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        logInfo('Starting http server...');
        self.httpServer = self.app.listen(self.options.port, () => {
            logInfo('Listening on port %O', self.options.port);
            resolve();
        }).on('error', () => {
            logError('Failed to start the server on port %O', self.options.port);
            reject();
        });
    });
}
```

How do i do "promisify" my connection close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i do "promisify" my connection close?

You can listen to the `close` event on the underlying http server returned from `listen` : https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close

## More

NOTE: A promise can only be resolved or rejected *once*, so you shouldn't `resolve` on listen anymore.

If you want to notify both listen and close and others use observable instead.

Comment: The `.listen()` callback is only called once so it works perfectly fine with a promise.  Presumably, the same would be true of a `close` event.  Promises work fine for events that only occur once.

Comment: It is not true with node clusters. Listen can be called several times.